Unable to deploy simple APEX class due to test error from another plugin
I am helping a client to develop a custom LWC component, and I need a simple apex function to generate a list of records for me. Since getRecords from 'lightning/uiRecordApi' requires specific ids, and I want to get a list of all records by the object api name. The only way I can think of is to use a apex class.
ProgramController.cls:
public with sharing class ProgramController {
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static List<cubbie_program__c> getActivePrograms() {
      return [SELECT Id, Name FROM cubbie_program__c];
  }
}

However, when I deploy this to production, I encounter an error. I tried SFDX: Run Apex Tests in vscode to find out what the issue was, and there is the output. I think most of the test case that failed is from a plugin called Varasi. Is there any way to bypass those test and deploy my code?
=== Test Summary
NAME                 VALUE             
───────────────────  ──────────────────
Outcome              Failed            
Tests Ran            50                
Pass Rate            88%               
Fail Rate            12%               
Skip Rate            0%                
Test Run Id          707OJ00000Ou0K2   
Test Execution Time  45919 ms          
Org Id               00Df4000004K6eREAS
Username             info@vibearts.ca  


=== Test Results
TEST NAME                                                                                              OUTCOME  MESSAGE                                                                                                                                                                        RUNTIME (MS)
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ───────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ────────────
attendanceControllerCustomTest.testGetRecords                                                          Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    2107        
attendanceControllerCustomTest.testGetRoles                                                            Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    15          
attendanceControllerCustomTest.testSaveEnrollment                                                      Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    886         
attendanceControllerCustomTest.testUpdateRecords                                                       Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    924         
fM2UpgradeManager_Test.upgradeAccounts_Test                                                            Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    576         
fM2UpgradeManager_Test.upgradeBenefits_Test                                                            Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    403         
fM2UpgradeManager_Test.upgradeCampaigns_Test                                                           Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    347         
fM2UpgradeManager_Test.upgradeContacts_Test                                                            Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    506         
fM2UpgradeManager_Test.upgradeOpportunities_Test                                                       Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    518         
fM2UpgradeManager_Test.upgradeOpportunityReceipts_Test                                                 Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    362         
fM2UpgradeManager_Test.upgradePaymentProcessors_Test                                                   Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    324         
fM2UpgradeManager_Test.upgradePayments_Test                                                            Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    387         
fM2UpgradeManager_Test.upgradeReceipts_Test                                                            Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    346         
fM2UpgradeManager_Test.upgradeTransactions_Test                                                        Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    413         
emailDataControllerTest.testGetPerformers                                                              Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    1458        
emailDataControllerTest.testGetProgramValue                                                            Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    21          
emailDataControllerTest.testGetSessions                                                                Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    759         
emailDataControllerTest.testSetProgramValue                                                            Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    21          
enrollmentControllerCustomTest.testDeleteRecords                                                       Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    2390        
enrollmentControllerCustomTest.testGetRecords                                                          Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    722         
enrollmentControllerCustomTest.testSendEmail                                                           Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    2302        
enrollmentControllerCustomTest.testUpdateLead                                                          Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    850         
enrollmentControllerCustomTest.testUpdateRecords                                                       Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    1040        
CreateSesionsCustomTest.TestCreateMultipleSessionMethod                                                Fail     System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Location: id value of incorrect type: a033i000004Ebk6AAC: [Location__c]  
                                                                                                                Class.CreateSessionsHelperCustom.CreateMultipleSession: line 64, column 1                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                Class.CreateSesionsCustomTest.TestCreateMultipleSessionMethod: line 13, column 1                                                                                                           
MyProfilePageControllerTest.testSave                                                                   Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    350         
css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.testCreateNewOpportunity                                              Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    15722       
css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.testGetCampaigns                                                      Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    107         
css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.testGetCampaignsByMode                                                Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    99          
css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.testGetIatsInfo                                                       Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    75          
css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.testGetSiteURL                                                        Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    16          
css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.testProcessOfflineDonationExistingContact_ReceiptEligibleNoBenefit    Fail     System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                Class.css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.checkResults: line 582, column 1                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                Class.css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.testProcessOfflineDonationExistingContact_ReceiptEligibleNoBenefit: line 217, column 1                                                              
css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.testProcessOfflineDonation_DeMinimusCheck                             Fail     System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                Class.css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.checkResults: line 582, column 1                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                Class.css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.testProcessOfflineDonation_DeMinimusCheck: line 364, column 1                                                                                       
css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.testProcessOfflineDonation_ReceiptEligibleNoBenefit                   Fail     System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                Class.css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.checkResults: line 582, column 1                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                Class.css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.testProcessOfflineDonation_ReceiptEligibleNoBenefit: line 186, column 1                                                                             
css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.testProcessOfflineDonation_ReceiptEligibleWithBenefitAmountAbove      Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    1739        
css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.testProcessOfflineDonation_ReceiptEligibleWithBenefitAmountBelow      Fail     System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                Class.css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.checkResults: line 582, column 1                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                Class.css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.testProcessOfflineDonation_ReceiptEligibleWithBenefitAmountBelow: line 246, column 1                                                                
css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.testProcessOfflineDonation_ReceiptEligibleWithBenefitPercentageAbove  Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    1700        
css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.testProcessOfflineDonation_ReceiptEligibleWithBenefitPercentageBelow  Fail     System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                Class.css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.checkResults: line 582, column 1                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                Class.css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.testProcessOfflineDonation_ReceiptEligibleWithBenefitPercentageBelow: line 305, column 1                                                            
css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.testSearchContacts                                                    Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    158         
css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.testWriteToLog                                                        Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    43          
css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.testbuildBrickworkPacket                                              Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    68          
css_GivingTuesdayController_Test.testcloudStackSettings                                                Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    20          
ChangePasswordControllerTest.testChangePasswordController                                              Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    13          
CommunitiesSelfRegConfirmControllerTest.testCommunitiesSelfRegConfirmController                        Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    10          
ForgotPasswordControllerTest.testForgotPasswordController                                              Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    17          
MicrobatchSelfRegControllerTest.testMicrobatchSelfRegController                                        Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    20          
CommunitiesLandingControllerTest.testCommunitiesLandingController                                      Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    7           
SiteLoginControllerTest.testSiteLoginController                                                        Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    13          
CommunitiesSelfRegControllerTest.testCommunitiesSelfRegController                                      Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    12          
SiteRegisterControllerTest.testRegistration                                                            Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    14          
CommunitiesLoginControllerTest.testCommunitiesLoginController                                          Pass                                                                                                                                                                                    10          


Do the tests fail without your updates? If so, someone needs to fix those first or you need to be very selective over tests to include in the change set.

Can you provide details on how you are deploying?  Are you using a changeset?  If so, you should choose the "With Specified Tests" option, and list only the Apex Test Class(es) needed to provide coverage for the non-test Class(es) in your deploy.  Otherwise, you are running all (non-packaged) tests in the org by default.

I am deploying directly from vs code to production. Is a better way to deploy to a sandbox and then use changeset to push the update to production?
